# How to perform an operation on a pandas column according to index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
data

   x
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
7  8
8  9 
9  10
```

Is there a way I can perform an operation on specific rows *by index*?

ie, I would like to subtract 1 from rows after index 3 and updating the initial column.

```
data

   x
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8 
9  9
```

I am also curious how you would go about this if you were to create an entirely new column

```
data['y'] = *some pandas function*

   x  y
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
4  5  4
5  6  5
6  7  6
7  8  7
8  9  8
9  10 9
```

I am aware you can use `np.where` when changing column values according to conditional values of another column, but I am trying to change the values of a column within a range of index values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can do it by `np.where`

```
df['y']=np.where(df.index>3,df.x-1,df.x)
df
Out[100]: 
    x  y
0   1  1
1   2  2
2   3  3
3   4  4
4   5  4
5   6  5
6   7  6
7   8  7
8   9  8
9  10  9
```